# How can I use Model functions correctly according to the MVC pattern in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

Can I do this **in a Controller**:

```
$this->User->read(null, $id);
$this->User->find('list');
```

Is it correct?

Am I using MVC correctly?

Can these **easy** functions be used in a Controller? Or, do I need to create these functions in the Model? Like `Model->getUser()`, and have that function use `Model->read()`.

I know that functions it's called by Model, but, when I want pass some parameters, and function makes big, for example:

```
$this->User->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.active' => true,
        'User.group_id' => 3,
        'User.age >=' => 18
    )
));
```

Can I **call this function in Controller**, or need create a custom function in Model, to call it? Like... `$this->User->findSomeCustomFunction($param1, $param2, $param3)`?

Comment: To correctly use MVC , you should be getting rid of CakePHP. It **does not** implement MVC design pattern. Active record instances are not "models", templates are not "views" and controllers are only responsible for changing the state of model **layer**.

Comment: I'm with @tereško on this; but, for that matter, I don't really understand how any back-end blocking frameworks implement the MVC pattern. For example, I'm a Django fan, which is alleged to be an MVC framework. However, it's difficult to discern the MVC components in Django, despite there being "models" and "views". I've never used CakePHP in any real capacity, but in my limited exposure I've also been puzzled by the MVC designation. With Cocoa/iOS development, the MVC is clear as day. Views delegate to controllers, which in turn work with models to update views.

Comment: @tereško Ya... If Cake is or not a MVC framework, I don't know (for me, it is). But for now... although not a 'mvc framework' which would be correct?

Comment: @dimadima I never use Ruby or Django, but I want... anyway, I just wanna know, in 'what point' I need create a function in Model, and not in Controller?

Comment: @PatrickMaciel, yeah, I think you're doing everything fine. Don't create more functions on the model if you can use the ones that are already on the model. And I think that's fine to do in the controller. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @PatrickMaciel: I mean, `$this->User->read(null, $id);` is already like `->getUser()`. Unless you need more logic, and unless you find yourself repeating that logic in other places, I would use the Model API provided by CakePHP. That's what it's there for.

Comment: By the way @PatrickMaciel, I really like your "I need study more. See you later."

Comment: Don't put find()s in your Controller.  You're just going to clutter your code, have many many more changes to break the DRY concept, and make programming in a team nightmarish. - my 2 cents.

Comment: @dimadima hahaha, it's true. I really need study more. A lot technologies, frameworks, and I'm here, with this 'newbie question' haha. By the way, thanks for your time.

Comment: @Dave thanks, I'll follow your instructions, and 'move' my finds to model. Thanks again.

Comment: @PatrickMaciel - Np!  glad I could convince you :)  I really think you'll be more happy w/ maintaining your code in the long run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR:**

It's "ok" to call a `find()` from your Controller, however **best practice is to put any/all find()s in your models**.

If you make a habit of putting all your `find()`s in your models, it will make it much easier to maintain your code in the long run.

**Explanation/example:**

In this case, as an example, you could start with a seemingly simple function:

```
//User model
public function getUsers() {
    return $this->find('list');
}
```

But later, maybe you need something more along the lines of:

```
//User model
public function getUsers($opts = array()) {
    $defaults = array(
        'findType' => 'all',
        'activeOnly' => true,
    );
    $params = array_merge($defaults, $opts);
    $qOpts = array('conditions' => array());        

    //active only
    if(!empty($params['activeOnly'])) $conditions[$this->alias.'.active'] = 1;

    return $this->find($params['findType'], $qOpts);
}
```

(Pardon if there are many ways to make that code better - it was just off the top of my head - It gives you the idea.)

Keeping all your `find()`s in the Model also keeps you from having to search through each Controller every time you want to write a `find()` to determine if you've used a similar `find()` anywhere else.  If you're programming as a team, that can be a nightmare, and you're almost guaranteed to be duplicating code.

Comment: Nice tips, every one appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly fine to call `Model->find()` from a Controller. However, you will also want follow the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principles. That basically means "Don't copy-paste code everywhere."

So, if you find that you need to make this exact `Model->find()` call from many Controller actions, it is considered good practice to abstract it into a function call against the Model. So yes, your Controllers would then call `$this->User->findSomeCustomFunction()`.